# Testing a Product that Includes Syncing and other Network Requests

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing, testing

I am nearing the release of an iOS app that syncs and otherwise interacts with a server.  I am struggling with a testing procedure that can cover most/all possible situations.  I don't have any experience with automated testing so I have been doing everything manually so far with the iPhone simulator and a physical device.

How would I start designing automated tests that can help me get better coverage of possible situations and also serve me well in the future as I make changes and add new features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to be more specific in your question. ie. outline how you communicate with your server, what technology is being employed etc.

But as a general approach the first thing I would be doing is looking to find a way to get reproducable results from the server. For example if I send a message asking for a record with an id of 'x' then the server will alwasy return the same record with the same data. There are severa ways to do this, one would be to load a set of test data into your server. Another would be to create a local test server and talk to that instead. Another option is to avoid the server all together in your automaticed tests and mock out the communication classes in your app. It totally depends on what you are trying to test and how.

Once you have your back end dealt with you can then look into automating the tests. This very much depends on how you have dealt with the server. For example, if you are performing an integration style test where you actually talk to a server, then the test might take the form:

1. Reset or clear the server data.
2. Load it with predictable data.
3. Run the iOS app using some testing framework and verify any data sent from the server.
4. Access the server and verify any changes made there.